# on an apk, after setting its debuggable option to false in the androidManifest file , a surprising message occurs. Why?

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-manifest, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I use Eclipse with Gluon and JavaFXports for developing an Android application.

After signing it with jarsigner (and zipaligning it too), I uploaded this apk to my Google Play console. And it says:
*"You uploaded a debuggable APK or Android App Bundle. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Find out more about debuggable APKs or Android App Bundles."*

So, I modified my androidManifest file by adding: application android:debuggable="false"

Then, under Eclipse, when I ran the AndroidInstall command  again, the result is now through Eclipse:

*":processAndroidResourcesDebugWarning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android); using existing value in manifest."*

**The "debuggable" notion could be implicitly defined elsewhere ?**

Note that there is no info about that in the build.gradle file (no "release", no "buildtypes", ..)

The SDK buildToolsVersion is '25.0.1'

At the end, Google Play Console accepts the modified file, now, as a not debuggable one

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: Did you forget to include what you added to your manifest?

Comment: a bad "<" is included in the text. Now, it is solved. The info "android:debuggable="false"" appears in the question